# Are normal curvature invariant by local conformal maps?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

**My idea:** I thought this was not true because if I consider is true. Than I would contradict the result that says that every two regular surfaces are locally conformal. Thus if this was true, then all normal curvature would be locally the same. However I couldn't find a good and satisfactory counterexample or example to suport my idea. Would you help me with this? How to prove this question?

Comment: Normal curvature is not even invariant under _global isometry_.

Comment: @Andrew Totally agree, but I was thinking in an example to respond to this question, I thought in plane and sphere. They are locally conformal but has not the same normal curvature. I was wondering how to formulate this answer. Or other examples.

Comment: As Andrew points out, even two isometric surfaces will in general have different normal curvatures (by which I assume you mean the second fundamental form). So a piece of the plane versus a piece of a cylinder is another simple example.

Comment: Thank you very much @Deane.